# Android app closes on when onBackPressed callled

Tags: android

I have a share button on my app. When the share button is clicked a share dialog opens with a list of sharing options. The probelm is when i decide i dont want to share(when the dialog is open) and press the back button on the phone, the app closes...how can i fix this??? i cant see the problem

```
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            dbControl = new DatabaseControl(ScoreMenu.this);
            dbControl.open();
            score = dbControl.fetchBestTime();
            dbControl.close();
            share(score);
        }
    });
}

public void share(String score){
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, ""));
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent goToMainScreen = new Intent(ScoreMenu.this, MainActivity.class);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        // Start activity with a custom animation
        Bundle bundle_animation = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(ScoreMenu.this,      R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left).toBundle();
        startActivity(goToMainScreen, bundle_animation);
    }
    else {                     
        startActivity(goToMainScreen);
    }
}
```

Hope you can help...

Comment: What's the stack trace from your logcat?

Comment: no errors logged in my logcat

Answer (score 0):

Closes how? Do you mean that another activity comes to the foreground?

In general, the back button pops the most recent activity off the top of the task stack. If there are more activities in the stack, the next one down comes to the foreground. If there *aren't* any more activities, control passes to the previous task (the previous app). If you started from Home, you'll go back to Home.

This is what's happening with your app. Since you're not building your own task stack that goes back to your app when you call startActivity() for the chooser, you're starting a new task. When you go "back", you pop out of this task to Home, rather than going back to your app.

Comment: The app closes totally...i have an intent that starts onBackPressed but it doesnt seem to call that...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using

```
finish();
```

After calling the activity you are currently in? (ScoreMenu i guess.)

Cause finish(); would kill the launcher activity while starting the new one.

Comment: Hi MonkeyDroid!...im not calling finish() anywhere in my activity

Answer (score 0):

After you call startActivity inside share(String score), the Share dialog opens, right? At this point, if the user press the back button, the dialog should go away, and your activity (ScoreMenu, I think) will be visible again. This is the default behavior, and you don't need to override onBackPressed to have it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply...yes the share dialog opens, I have removed the onBackPressed method and and when I press the back button it still closes the application, no errors or crashes in the log

Comment: Problem solved...in my manifest I had android:noHistory="true" on my score menu activity...man im a noob!